# Sending emails through Gmail on Rails app + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

I opened a Google Apps account and registered email. I am trying to connect it to my Rials app running on Heroku with sidekiq. Letter opener works well on the development side so the setting is fine but sending emails with Google does not work.

This is config/initializers/mailer.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.helper "application"
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {   
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               domain.com,
  user_name:            name@domain.com,
  password:             gmailpassword,
  authentication:       'plain',
  # authentication:       'login',
  tls:                  true,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'domainname.com' }
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

In Google I turned off the 2 step Verification, I turned on the less secure apps etc but it is not working. Either it is showing Authenticate Error. During changing setting etc I experienced three errors:

1. SMTPAuthenticationError
2. Uncaught exception: 534-5.7.14
3. OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol

Any idea how to fix it and set up gmail correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [what was said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43848381/1923858) you also need to go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha while logged into the gmail account you're attempting to send through. I can confirm this worked for me on Heroku today.

Comment: Careful as this may not stay long! After one week I got it not working again. :(

Answer (score 0):

Smtp setting in config/application.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :user_name => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      :password => "xxxxxx",
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

visit your gmail settings and enable less secure apps to get the application working. link: google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps